# Is it possible to create variables and keyvault variables in same variable group in azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a requirement to create variables and key vault variables in the same variable group instead of multiple variable groups. Is there any way to configure variables and keyvault variables/secrets in the same variable group in azure devops. Please help me to how to do this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there's a way to create variables and key vault variables in the same variable group instead of multiple variable groups.

We have to create a separate variable group and link an existing Azure key vault to map selective vault secrets to the variable group.

Please see [Add & use variable groups](https://devops/pipelines) and [Link secrets from an Azure key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault) for details.